# How to build dev and run docker images?

Tags: docker

I have an C/C++ project and would like to build 2 images from alpine for development and run separately.

- The dev image: Install all development environment like gcc, cmake, libraries with dev packages (ex: boost-dev).
- The run image: Contains only the binary files after success build from dev image, and only normal library package for running (ex: boost).

So the run image has minimal size compare to the dev image.

Can I use 1 Dockerfile to build both 2 images? I did some research with ONBUILD instruction but didn't find out with the solution.

Please help me how to solve this.

Thanks & regards,

Anh

Comment: Please post code so others can help you. [https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

It used to be that this would require two Docker images, but recent versions of Docker support [multi-stage builds](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/multistage-build/). This will allow you to meet your goal with a single `Dockerfile`.

You can read the linked doc for details, but the idea is that your `Dockerfile` is divided into multiple stages, each beginning with a new `FROM` line.  Only the last stage is used to generate the final output image, and it can access the filesystems from the other stages by index.  The example from the docs:

```
FROM golang:1.7.3
WORKDIR /go/src/github.com/alexellis/href-counter/
RUN go get -d -v golang.org/x/net/html  
COPY app.go .
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -a -installsuffix cgo -o app .

FROM alpine:latest  
RUN apk --no-cache add ca-certificates
WORKDIR /root/
COPY --from=0 /go/src/github.com/alexellis/href-counter/app .
CMD ["./app"]
```

Here, the first stage builds a Go application, while the second stage builds an image with the compiled executable, which it copies from the first stage using the `--from=0` argument to the `COPY` directive.